# Powershell Save HttpWebRequest Response as PDF file

Tags: powershell, httpwebresponse

I can send HTTP POST webrequest successfully, however, I am unable to save the response as a pdf file.  This is part of the code I have and it gives me corrupted pdf file.

```
[System.IO.Stream] $outputStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()  
$outputStream.Write($bytes,0,$bytes.Length) 
[System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = [System.IO.StreamReader]$request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()

$Wrt = [System.IO.File]::Create("C:\Users\geer\report.pdf")
$Buffer = New-Object Byte[] 1024

Do {
$BytesRead = $sr.Read($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)
$Wrt.Write($Buffer, 0, $BytesRead)
} While ($BytesRead -gt 0)

$sr.close()
$sr.Dispose()

$Wrt.Flush()
$Wrt.Close()
$Wrt.Dispose()
```

Please note, I cannot use invoke-webrequest or webclient because there are specific headers that I can only send through httpwebrequest.

Looking forward to any feedback I can get.

Thanks

Comment: Is the file you're saving the full size you expect it to be? Thinking that if the response is being chunked you're not making the subsequent requests to get all the bits of the file, possibly hence the corruption.

Comment: Yes, I do believe it is the full size expected with first response.

Comment: Is this a valid method to output to PDF?  I would assume you need some sort of encoder, not just sending a byte stream to a file with the .pdf extension.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I thought so too but I just didn't know how to encode it. But, I got this working with invoke-webrequest and using -outfile param.  I'm so glad!!

Comment: What does `$sr.CurrentEncoding` return and what are the first 3 byte of the saved file?